# javascript replace() same word different replacement

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing a command where you enter for ex. `I'm a noun`,  the command returns `I'm a <random noun>`, same for verbs and adjectives, however, I am facing a problem. I want replace() to replace every `noun` for example with a random noun, but not the same one, so I can't use /g.

This is what I have so far:

```
  const arga = args;
  const start = [arga];
  console.log(start);
for (let i=0;i<start.length;i++) {
    console.log(start[i][i]);
 if (start[i][i] == "adjective") 
  arg.join("").replace("adjective",randA(adjs));
 if (start[i][i] == "noun") arga.join(" ").replace("noun", randA(nouns));
 if (start[i][i] == "number") arga.join(" ").replace("number", rand());
 if (start[i][i] == "verb") arga.join(" ").replace("verb", randA(verbs));
}
message.channel.send(arga);
```

A few notes:

- `arga.replace` is not a function without the .join() (or anything else of that sort), so that must be present
- Right now the command doesn't do anything, just posts the args.
- it's `[i][i]` because right now it's a double array, like `[ [ 'Hello', 'there,', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'today' ] ]`, [i][i] does get the right thing.
- The arrays are huge

Comment: what do you mean by _I want replace() to replace every noun for example with a random noun, but not the same one,_ ?

Comment: For Ex, `I am a noun noun noun` i want all 3 `noun` to be different, but the problem is that only the first one will be replaced, or all if I add /g, but they're gonna be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use global `replace`, just pass a function (not a function invocation, just a function), and select from an array without replacement (remove the random item from the array when it's selected), for example:

```js
const str = "I'm a noun and a noun and a noun and yet another noun";
const nounReplacer = (() => {
  const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'corge'];
  return () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
  };
})();
console.log(str.replace(/\bnoun\b/g, nounReplacer));
```

Comment: The `verbs, adjectives and nouns` arrays are huge, it'd be pointless to remove one of them, which makes this method useless.

Comment: You didn't say that in your question, but you did say you wanted the nouns to all be different - this is one way to accomplish that. Another method without mutating the original array would be to push each selected item to an array and, when trying to find a random word, make sure that the array of already-selected words does not `includes` the new word.